# Why do images display in raw file URL, but NOT in html display using Chrome? Other browsers are fine

Tags: google-chrome

As of October 1, images that are hosted on our server, will NOT display in Chrome for any users when the image is trying to display in html. It works fine in all other browsers. If I paste the exact URL of the image file in the browser, the image works.

example:
This image displays fine here if I paste into my browser:
http://example.com/email/2020/09/file.jpg

But, when the image is included in an html page, the image does not display.  i.e. in a webpage, the images show up as missing.

I've discovered that images from other servers work just fine.  Why would one server work and another not.  I'm trying to get an answer to our I.T. department to let them know if they need to update something on our servers to fix this issue, or if this is a Chrome issue that Google needs to fix?

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you read the release notes to the latest update to Chrome?

Comment: Hi David... I"m not sure where to go do that? I'm not a programmer - trying to help find the solution to this issue.  Can you direct me where that is?